# Pass Hidden Fields with the Same Name. Will PHP Get Them as Array?

Tags: php

If I have a form with hidden fields in this format:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mydata[]" value="one">
<input type="hidden" name="mydata[]" value="two">
<input type="hidden" name="mydata[]" value="three">
```

Will I be able to access these three values as an array with $_REQUEST?

Comment: You can process them using a foreach instruction if you want

Comment: **Yes,** why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The result should be something like this:

```
print_r($_REQUEST['mydata']);

array
(
    0 => "one",
    1 => "two",
    2 => "three"
)

echo $_REQUEST['mydata'][1]; // echos  "two"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes (since the names end in `[]`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. These values will be in an array and numerated from 0 to n. First input will be always at key 0 and so on.